# python: fast lightweight persistence

Tags: python, persistence

I'm writing a python program that runs on a rather slow phone (as well as other platforms).  Reading in data on the phone with pickle takes about 2 seconds and simplejson is significantly slower. The phone runs python 2.5.4

The data are in various lists and dictionaries in a group of classes.  I can convert to and from a json format relatively quickly.  The bulk of the time seems to be in pickle or json processing, as just reading or writing the json or pickle file is much faster than using pickle or json.

The program has to read the entire dataset and to write it periodically.

I suppose I could create some way to translate the data to text and see if that's faster, but reinventing the wheel is seldom a worthwhile endeavor.

What other storage alternatives might make sense?

Comment: How much data are we talking about here, byte-wise?

Comment: What `json` module are you using?

Comment: @cheeken: Likely in the 100kb - 200kb range

Comment: @lunaryorn: it's a version simplejson 2 in pure python written for the phone

Comment: @anurag: currently working with a Nokia c6-00 and pys60 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) module? According to [these benchmarks](http://kbyanc.blogspot.com/2007/07/python-serializer-benchmarks.html) it is significantly faster than pickle. **However**, make *very sure* to read and understand the warnings at the top of the documentation.

Also, just to make sure: did you use `cPickle`? If not, try that — it's significantly faster than `pickle`.

Alternatively, since your data are fairly simple, you could write your own using [pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/). If you want to go that route, the [MsgPack serializer](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python/blob/master/msgpack/_msgpack.pyx#L85) would be a good starting point.

Comment: Please, don't use `marshal`.  The format is undocumented, potentially subject to change, limited in supported types, and unsafe with regards to corrupted data.

Comment: If the OP is dealing with a controlled environment, it doesn't seem like this would be an issue (ie, because they could trivially checksum the data and make sure that the version of Python doesn't change). I've updated my answer with a warning, though.

Comment: from my own arbitrary tests with python 2.7 on an x86 desktop: marshal is really really fast (14x faster than cpickle), and cpickle is about 30% faster than json.

Comment: I'll try marshall. I'd read the first few paragraphs and it didn't seem appropriate.  It is a controlled environment. I'm using cPickle.

Comment: Ok, cool. And, ya — if marshall isn't appropriate and cpickle is too slow, the next best thing will be a C extension, possibly written with pyrex. MsgPack claims to be very fast, so you might be able to drop them in… But make sure you're aware of their limitations (ex, they don't support `unicode`, I don't think they support recursive data).

Comment: Marshal is much faster than pickle, but "marshal cannot be used to serialize user-defined classes and their instances," so I have to convert class instances to dicts, lists, etc.  pickle: load, 2.0, dump, 0.6; marshal: load, 0.5, convert to class instances, 0.5, convert to marshal format, 0.2, dump, 0.5